# Metrics on "market share" for server-side scripting languages

Tags: python, server-side-scripting

Does anyone know of any market share information for server-side scripting languages (# of web servers, % of web servers, etc.)?

I'm learning how to do server-side scripting with Python (via the examples in Programming Python). I just can't ever remember having seen a web address with ".py?" in it ... they're almost all ".php?" or ".asp?".

Thanks,

Mike

Comment: Those extensions aren't needed for the code to work. It just so happens that PHP and ASP (and some other environments) use the filesystem to structure their apps (which is stupid, but that's a separate argument).

Comment: "I just can't ever remember having seen a web address with ".py?""  There's a trick to that.  It's called "frameworks".  What you really want to know about are Python frameworks.

Comment: Oh, meaning Django, Pylons, Zope, etc? Which leads me to another question ... (soon to be posted).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**I've found these stats to be the best:**

- http://w3techs.com/technologies/overview/programming_language/all

If you click any of the server-side languages listed, it'll tell you the the 10 most popular sites using that language. The page also breaks down what % of each version is being used.

**Here's an overview of how they did the research, which to me makes sense:**

- http://w3techs.com/technologies

Comment: W3Techs has useful stats, but TIOBE has more detailed metrics IMO. It's hard to determine what server-side language is used on some sites, and they also exclude the usage of these languages outside of the web (intranet apps) or the volume of code being written in each language. If you want to look at job market prospects, TIOBE has a better overview, and they also show growth trends over time.

Answer (score 4):

http://www.tiobe.com/index.php/content/paperinfo/tpci/index.html

Comment: More of a popularity index than a market share index, and not specific to server-side programming. Still a nice resource.

Answer (score 0):

Netcraft will let you know what a site is running... thats a good place to do some research..